# Maven Jelly plugin exception in Maven1.x

Tags: maven

Will maven jelly plugin work with Java 1.7?
I need to call ant build script from maven1.x with 1.7 jvm. I used maven jelly plugin but i get the below exception 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.DelegatingJavacTask$ExposingJavac.getTempdir()Ljava/io/File;
        at weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.DelegatingJavacTask.getTempdir(DelegatingJavacTask.java:170)
        at weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.JwsModule.initialize(JwsModule.java:315)
        at weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.JwsModule.build(JwsModule.java:254)
        at weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.JwscTask.execute(JwscTask.java:229)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:341)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:309)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:336)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1339)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:397)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:341)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.ant.AntTag.doTag(AntTag.java:185)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:279)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:135)
        at org.apache.maven.jelly.tags.werkz.MavenGoalTag.runBodyTag(MavenGoalTag.java:79)
        at org.apache.maven.jelly.tags.werkz.MavenGoalTag$MavenGoalAction.performAction(MavenGoalTag.java:110)
        at com.werken.werkz.Goal.fire(Goal.java:639)
        at com.werken.werkz.Goal.attain(Goal.java:575)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginManager.attainGoals(PluginManager.java:671)
        at org.apache.maven.MavenSession.attainGoals(MavenSession.java:263)
        at org.apache.maven.jelly.tags.maven.ReactorTag.doTag(ReactorTag.java:368)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:279)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:135)
        at org.apache.maven.jelly.tags.werkz.MavenGoalTag.runBodyTag(MavenGoalTag.java:79)
        at org.apache.maven.jelly.tags.werkz.MavenGoalTag$MavenGoalAction.performAction(MavenGoalTag.java:110)
        at com.werken.werkz.Goal.fire(Goal.java:639)
        at com.werken.werkz.Goal.attain(Goal.java:575)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginManager.attainGoals(PluginManager.java:671)
        at org.apache.maven.MavenSession.attainGoals(MavenSession.java:263)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.App.doMain(App.java:488)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.App.main(App.java:1239)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.werken.forehead.Forehead.run(Forehead.java:551)
        at com.werken.forehead.Forehead.main(Forehead.java:581)

The Build script runs fine with ant seperately.

Answer (score 0):

Maven1.x Jelly plugin will not work with java 1.7 so i have to change my maven build script to externally call ant.